# Doctrine: Set primary Key

Tags: php, database, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a table with some fields and the first is my primary key, called `token`.

I need that token isn't automatically, so, I want to set this value. For example,

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$object->setToken("first");
$object->setValue("123");
$em->persist($object);
$em->flush();
```

But, in my DB, always token is `null`, why?

When I do flush, token value disappear.

In my entity, token is declared:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * Set token
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return Downloads
     */
    public function setToken($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get token
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try with your own AbstractIdGenerator using @GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM") and @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="App\Entity\YourOwnGenerator")? See [link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#customidgenerator)

Answer (score 5):

Try with `ORM\GeneratedValue`

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $token;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help [Doctrine2 Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929186/doctrine2-primary-key).

And if you did not create your table using the `doctrine` command check if `$token` set to `Primary Key` in your database.

Comment: thanks, but this isn't the problem, I have annotation, only primari key is stored like a default value.